# Can't delete and reinstall Python 3 because of new user folder name

Tags: python, windows, installation, uninstallation, administrator

I started to learn Python and got stuck on my own language (I'm not English Native Speaker), main user folder name was by kirilitsa.

It cause trouble with installing new elements to Python. I changed name and now console don't see Python, I tried to reinstall manual and from Control panel but still it somehow exist in my pc and I can't repair, modify or uninstall it.

I think there is a path which lead to old version of folder name but I can't even imagine where it can be.

**Is there any solution or to reinstall windows will be faster?**

- It shows right way but...:

[image]

- Changed path:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: check environment variable PATH from control panel>system

Comment: @frab already was changed to new one and stil...

Comment: You could simply install Anaconda and let it overwrite the windows python path. For me that works. Anyway, could you show your PATH variable?

Comment: @Dodik Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)

Comment: Just press right buttton in My Computer >  'Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables >  Then search of 'Path' and double click it,. if you see a PATH of Python already installed deleted it. Then go and install again Python and flag the 'Add Python to envirorment variables' is even in the screenshot u add

Comment: @Dschoni https://imgur.com/a/UeLeufy PATH

Comment: @Federico Baù https://imgur.com/a/UeLeufy

Comment: @Dodik ok that's good. man when you installed Python did you flagged 'Add Python to envirorment variables' ? you can see it in the Screenshot

Comment: @Federico Baù I can't, it thinks there is Python already installed and doesnt send me to install screen, it sends me to Modify, Repair and Uninstall https://imgur.com/e2omjfJ

Comment: " install screen, it sends me to Modify" if so,add a screenshot !!                      
 [check this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=In%20your%20toolbar%20when%20typing,you're%20hosting%20it%20elsewhere.)  Also, you can have different Python installed, actually everytime you create an envirorment you install a new Python everytime! is not that the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 months later I'm found how to fix the problem.
After several wrong deletion of Python 3.9.1 which screwd up things there still was some in system installer, like this but 3.9.1 version:
[image]

You need to kill them all before u could install new version or update. Good proggram which I used: Reg Organizer.
Install it, open important sections registry, find all python 3.9.1 or version you have problem with and delete:
[image]
Done! Worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

From the Official  [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#finding-the-python-executable).

Do this

**Modifying an Existing Installation:**

Re-run your installer (e.g. in Downloads, python-3.8.4.exe) and Select "Modify".
Check all the optional features you want (likely no changes), then click [Next]. Check [x] "Add Python to environment variables", and [Install].
[image]

### UPDATE

NOTE:

I see that from screenshot you are installing the 64-bit Python, what version is your Window?

if is 32-bit then just go [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and get the 32 bit ([32 bit here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.7/python-3.8.7-embed-win32.zip))

[image]

### Run Installer as Amministrator

- [Have Windows “Run” dialog run as Admin?](https://superuser.com/questions/203068/have-windows-run-dialog-run-as-admin)
- [How To Run Programs As Administrator In Windows 10](https://www.itechtics.com/run-programs-administrator/)

---

If you still get an error, go manually to your folder, as per screenshot the path should be:

```
C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\
```

Follow this instruction

### **[How to add to the PYTHONPATH in Windows, so it finds my modules/packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)**

**Add**

```
C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
```

**And**

```
C:\Users\Timur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
```

Comment: Even with all of features: https://imgur.com/17ZH53t

Comment: @Dodik you need to run it as Administrator, check my answer

Comment: Trying to install old version but it sees "new version" and sends me off https://imgur.com/hUCo9s2  https://imgur.com/GPkrXL6 try 3.8 version?

Comment: Done by admin: https://imgur.com/7r8jPtG dif error and it created folder with old name: https://imgur.com/m4GHd4i but install didnt run full only docs installed before error

Comment: @Dodik yes but I see again that from the installer you didn't select 'Add Python 3,9 to PATH'

Comment: I told already, it's old version and even if I check path it tells me there is a new version installed, tryed PYTHONPATH - didn't worked. I'll try now to install 3.8

Comment: 3.8.6 easy installed, until next update of 3.9 I think will be unable to do smt with it. I'm afraid there is nothing to do with PATH, it's somewhere else in registry editor maybe

Comment: @Dodik I'm happy you installed the 3.8 but honestly this is weird. I tell you what. the best thing now is think about this another day u see it will work eventually.

Comment: yeah, I think so too. Thanks for help.

Comment: I would still be very curious on this. I had issues before with the python installer when running on non-ASCII folders. You definitely want to have a clean install at some point, which is why I recommended Anaconda above.

Answer (score 0):

I too deleted python by mistake and found that I was unable to uninstall or reinstall. When I launched the python installer, the only options I could choose from were - Modify, Repair, Uninstall. Neither modify nor uninstall worked since I got the same message 'No Python 3.9 installation was detected'.
It was perfectly solved using Repair option. I then chose to uninstall completely and reinstall. It would probably also be a good idea to check the environment variable 'Path' and also Registry Editor to make sure there is nothing left over from the previous installation.